# How to pass all the values in the table in ssrs when there is no value in the parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am passing two parameters i.e `@AccountId` and `@key`. I want to show all the values present in the database for `@AccountId` and `@key` when there is no values in the parameters i.e `@AccountId` and `@key`. I want to do this for the same dataset. Is this possible or i have create different datasets?

The query which I am using is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDenyList]
@AccountId nvarchar(100),
@key nvarchar(400)
AS
select New_AccountId AS 'AccountId/Key', New_Description AS 'Reason',CreatedOn AS 'Date'
  from abc.dbo.New_keydenylist 
 where New_AccountId is not null
   AND @AccountId = New_AccountId
 union all
select new_key AS 'AccountId/Key', New_Description AS 'Reason',CreatedOn AS 'Date' 
  from abc.dbo.New_keydenylist 
 where New_key is not null
   and @Key=New_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you have to use any predicate that always evaluate to true regardless to the parameters' values passed to the `WHERE` clause. For example `WHERE 1 = 1`:

```
 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND (@AccountId IS NOT NULL OR AccountId = @AccountId)
```

The same with `@key` parameter:

```
 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND (@key IS NOT NULL OR New_key = @key)
```

If the two parameters `@key` and `@AccountId` are both `NULL` or one of them, then the `WHERE` clause still be valid and return all the row as it were not presented.

Comment: I want that all the values should be displayed only when there is no input in the parameters and the correct values should be displayed for the input parameters

Comment: @user1677027, This will displayed all the values when there is no input in the parameters i.e. if the two parameters are `NULL` isn't that what you are looking for? Can you clarify more?

Comment: The values are comming but the parameters are not giving the right results. It always gives all the values when we select the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Check for null or equivalence on the parameter:

```
AND ((@AccountId IS NULL) OR (@AccountId = New_AccountId))
```